# Link User Commits to my Github

Tags: git, github

This weekend I was working on a project when my laptop failed. I ended up using a lab computer to code and commit and push work. I authenticated with my GitHub credentials every time, so I assumed the work would be linked to my account. Instead it says U-ACCOUNTS{my_name} as the commit author. I imagine this is because I didn't set the config with my email and name.

Is there any way after the fact to link this to my account. Right now U-ACCOUNTS{my_name} does not even show up on the contributes page.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you can't do that if no email was set, according to [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/), you can only link future commits if no email was set on your local git config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply authenticating with your GitHub details isn't enough; what matters is the actual email address listed as the committer for each commit. This is because you could conceivably want to push up a bunch of commits to your account which weren't by you.

I am afraid the only way you'd be able to achieve this is to recomit everything with your correct email address set.